# How to efficiently display errors in C?

Tags: c, error-handling, flags

I tried a new way of protecting my code through some binary flags.
I think binary flags are very handy in such situations because it is easy to check for conditions, for example the FAILURE flag below that tells if a failure occured or not is very easy to code.
Issue is it is easy to get tangled up with 1-digit difference flags.

```c
# define EXIT_FLAG              0b10000000000000000000000000000000

# define FAILURE                0b00000000000000000001111111111111
# define FAILED_FORK            0b00000000000000000000000000000001
# define FAILED_WAITPID         0b00000000000000000000000000000010
# define FAILED_SEM_OPEN        0b00000000000000000000000000000100
# define FAILED_SEM_CLOSE       0b00000000000000000000000000001000
# define FAILED_SEM_POST        0b00000000000000000000000000010000
# define FAILED_SEM_WAIT        0b00000000000000000000000000100000
# define FAILED_SEM_UNLINK      0b00000000000000000000000001000000
# define FAILED_CREAT_TH        0b00000000000000000000000010000000
# define FAILED_JOIN_TH         0b00000000000000000000000100000000
# define FAILED_KILL            0b00000000000000000000001000000000
# define FAILED_GET_TIME        0b00000000000000000000010000000000
# define FAILED_USLEEP          0b00000000000000000000100000000000
# define FAILED_WRITE           0b00000000000000000001000000000000

# define USERGUIDE              0b00000000000000000010000000000000
# define USERGUIDE_MSG          "usage:\n\t./philo {nb_philos} {die_tm} \
                                {eat_tm} {sleep_tm} (max_eat)\n \
                                \tinputs in ms is capped to 60,000 ms\n"

int ft_putstr_fd(char *s, int fd)
{
    if (s)
    {
        while (*s)
        {
            if (write(fd, s++, 1) == -1)
            {
                write(fd, "Failed write\n", 13);
                return (0);
            }
        }
    }
    return (1);
}

int ft_putstr_error(char *s)
{
    return (ft_putstr_fd(s, STDERR_FILENO));
}

void    *ft_puterror(int flag, void *args)
{
    if (flag & FAILED_FORK)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed fork: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_WAITPID)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed waitpid: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_SEM_OPEN)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed sem_open: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_SEM_CLOSE)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed sem_close: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_SEM_POST)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed sem_post: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_SEM_WAIT)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed sem_wait: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_SEM_UNLINK)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed sem_unlink: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_CREAT_TH)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed create thread: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_JOIN_TH)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed joining thread: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_KILL)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed kill: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_GET_TIME)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed get_time: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_USLEEP)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed usleep: ");
    else if (flag & FAILED_WRITE)
        ft_putstr_error("Failed write: ");
    if (flag & FAILURE)
    {
        ft_putstr_error((char *)args);
        ft_putstr_error("\n");
    }
    if (flag & USERGUIDE)
        ft_putstr_error(USERGUIDE_MSG);
    return (NULL);
}
```

Would you recommend to use this method to handle such errors or is there a nicer way, like a best practice ?

Comment: A bitmap makes sense if two or more errors can be active at the same time. Your reporting doesn't allow that, so simple plain distinct numbers would be fine. They could then be indexes into an array for the error message. And why do `ft_puterror` return a `void *`? It could just as well be returning plain `void` (not the lack of the `*`). And if you want to print the argument as a string, why not have it as a `char *` type to begin with?

Comment: If you are reporting the errors exclusively why do you need a bit flag? You only need them if there might be a combination of errors to report. Quite often, there isn't, because having met one error, there is no sense continuing.

Comment: I use it so that it is easy for me to specify the argument of ft_puterror and to make it easy for the FAILURE flag + my flag could contain other infos about variables to free for example ? I could have a type void indeed, but it is more convenient in my code to return NULL

Comment: If you don't have an actual value to return, then don't return a value. It's even more easy to not return anything, than having to explicitly need to return `NULL`. And if no caller even cares about the returned value, that make even less sense. Not to mention it will confuse all users of your code.

Comment: If the above code compiles fine and is working, then include some code that uses this functionality and post it on codereview.com.

Comment: I did not know of this website, I will, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much less error-prone if you use a sequence of numbers for the failure codes. Whenever you need a bitmask, simply shift one bit N times to the left, e.g.

```
//specify failure code type
typedef uint32_t failure_t;

//create a bitmask of the specified failure code
#define FAILURE_MASK(FCODE) (((failure_t) 1) << (FCODE))

//list of failure constants
#define NO_FAILURE          ((failure_t) 0) //add a no failure flag
#define FAILED_FORK         ((failure_t) 1)
#define FAILED_WAITPID      ((failure_t) 2)
#define FAILED_SEM_OPEN     ((failure_t) 3)
#define FAILED_SEM_CLOSE    ((failure_t) 4)
#define FAILED_SEM_POST     ((failure_t) 5)
#define FAILED_SEM_WAIT     ((failure_t) 6)
#define FAILED_SEM_UNLINK   ((failure_t) 7)
#define FAILED_CREAT_TH     ((failure_t) 8)
#define FAILED_JOIN_TH      ((failure_t) 9)
#define FAILED_KILL         ((failure_t) 10)
#define FAILED_GET_TIME     ((failure_t) 11)
#define FAILED_USLEEP       ((failure_t) 12)
#define FAILED_WRITE        ((failure_t) 13)
//... extend as you see fit
#define FAILURE_N           (FAILED_WRITE + 1) //useful for iteration

//list of failure strings
static const char *failure_strings[FAILURE_N] = {
    "No failure",
    "Failed fork",
    "...",
    "Failed write"
};

//extern function to retrieve the failure string
const char* get_failure_string(failure_t failure)
{
    return failure_strings[failure];
}

//test if the failure set contains the specified failure
#define is_failure_set(FSET, FCODE) FSET & FAILURE_MASK(FCODE)

//set the failure code in the failure set
#define set_failure(FSET, FCODE) FSET |= FAILURE_MASK(FCODE)

/**/

void *ft_puterror(failure_t failure_set, void *args)
{
    if (failure_set == NO_FAILURE) //no failure set, nothing to do ...
        return NULL;               //unless no failure should be reported too

    //for each failure that is set in failure_set
    for (failure_t n=1; n < FAILURE_N; ++n, failure_set >>= 1) {
        if (failure_set & 1) { //failure n is set, report it
            ft_putstr_error(get_failure_string(n));
            ft_putstr_error((char *)args);
            ft_putstr_error("\n");
        }
    }

    //...

    return NULL;
}
```

Adding a new failure code requires only 3 steps:

- add a new const, e.g. `#define FAILED_NEW ((failure_t) 14)`
- set the constant `FAILURE_N` to the appropriate value, e.g. `#define FAILURE_N (FAILED_NEW + 1)`
- add a new string to the `failure_strings` table, e.g. `"Failed new"`

---

**Edit:** based on the suggestions of 'chux - Reinstate Monica' (see comments below).

Comment: Should `typedef uint64_t failure_t;` change to `typedef uint32_t failure_t;` or `typedef uint128_t failure_t;` or ..., using `((failure_t)0)` instead of `UINT64_C(0)` reduces maintenance issues.

Comment: Consider `#define FAILURE_N  (FAILED_WRITE + 1)`, then we can use `n < FAILURE_N` (more C idiomatic) and `static const char *failure_strings[FAILURE_N]` to help coordinate array size.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's a good suggestion. But what bugs me the most is, that we waste one (precious) bit for the `NO_FAILURE` flag `(1 << 0 = 1)`. In my mind, 'no failure' is not a failure, therefore it shouldn't be listed in the flags and be an independent value.